# Is it a good idea to use global variables to store DB handles in a Go web application?

Tags: web, go, global-variables

Official guide says it's okay to use a global variable to cache templates:

http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

> First we create a global variable named templates, and initialize it
>   with ParseFiles.

Can global variables be used to store DB handles and repository objects? Or do they have to be initialized for every request?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine, it's used in the official Go packages all over the place, now if you gonna modify these objects from your handlers, you will have to use a mutex so you wouldn't run into races.

Comment: Thanks! But what would you do with unclosed connections? With local handles it's always easy to close them at the end of request. Or is it normal to have 1 open connection for millions of requests for days?

Comment: Database connections? yeah that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Coming from ASP.NET where having a global db connection was a terrible idea.

Comment: It can easily be a terrible idea in Go as well. Depends on details.

Comment: It may well be a terrible idea to produce any API for others to use if that API *requires* a particular global variable. It's even worse if the global variables make decoupled testing harder. With these provisos in mind, global variables in Go are typically package-private vars that don't leak across boundaries. As such, they're not inherently evil at all.

Comment: DB connections in Go are typically pools, so a global isn't a terrible thing. Worth reading this though to see how to move away from globals where possible: https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091